# generate two different forms in html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dynamic

I wanna build two different surfaces in my html form with a lot of input tags. Lets say I have Users form type Employee and Customer. When an Employee is logged in, the form should have selectboxes in certain places, and when the customer is logged in, it should be replaced by input-tags. So far I use something like

```
<html>
<div id="myDynamicContent"></div>
</html>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

  })

  function fill_it() {
    if(employee) {
      $('#myDynamicContent').append('<selectbox>...</selectbox>')
    } else {
      $('#myDynamicContent').append('<input>...</input>')
    }

  }
</script>
```

Is there a more elegant way to do that or is it good enough.

Comment: Its better to make two diff view as per your requirement and load them using ajax call.

Comment: have your html static generating two different form and just make visible corresponding `form` depending upon the condition.

Comment: what the other commenters said. have static html for both cases, but enclose the different bits in containers that you can show/hide depending on the form type. hard-coding HTML generation code into javascript is more complex and will just make your app harder to maintain